# Compile error "Type 'MyMigration' already defines a member called 'Up' with the same parameter types

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I have a very simple code-first dotnet core webapi project generated from netcoreapp2.1 in VSCode and I also added two migrations using `dotnet ef migrations add [migration-name]`. Everything seems to work as expected, except I suddenly get this compile error (you can disregard the brackets in the migration name):

> Type '[migration-name]' already defines a member called 'Up' with the same parameter types

Technically I know *why* this happens but I'm note sure if this is intentional behavior when working with migrations. Is it expected to update the namespace every time a new migration is created or am I missing something obvious here?

I did a couple of google searches for this issue but surprisingly I did not get any hits that covered this issue.

Comment: are you adding both migrations with the same name?

Comment: Hi @viveknuna maybe you already read my answer but no, the names were different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause for this - I previously removed some of the failed migrations by deleting the files instead of using `dotnet ef migrations remove` and so I had an obsolete .cs file with the same methods in my migration folder. Removing the file solved the problem.